# killing processes automatically

Tags: shell-script, awk, process, kill

I need to kill all processes in a certain shell, excluding certain processes.

For example, `sh`, which is my shell, and the command.

This is what is currently in my shell right now.

```
rcihp146 :/home/msingh2> ps
   PID TTY       TIME COMMAND
  8880 pts/258   0:00 ps
  5908 pts/258   0:00 sh
```

But if there are some extra processes I would like to kill all of them, excluding the above two.

I tried a one-liner for this purpose and it didn't work:

```
rcihp146 :/home/msingh2> ps | awk '{system("kill -9 $1")}'
sh: kill: The number of parameters specified is not correct.
sh: kill: The number of parameters specified is not correct.
sh: kill: The number of parameters specified is not correct.
sh: kill: The number of parameters specified is not correct.
```

... but it works if I only give a specific pid like below:

```
 rcihp146 :/home/msingh2> ps | awk '{system("kill -9 23456")}'
```

I need to exclude two or three process (like `ps`, `sh`) from being killed.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what you do and don't want to kill. Could you post a process list with actual stuff to kill, and explain on what criteria a process should live or die?

Comment: Ok, I just want processname **sh** excluded and rest all killed

Comment: inclusion of ps does not matter since it will be executed instantaneously. It'll be gone even if you don't kill it. Still you can remove ` && $4 != "ps"` from my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course the one liner you wrote won't work since the $1 is inside the quotes. Try this:

```
ps| gawk '{ if ($4 != "COMMAND" && $4 != "sh" && $4 != "ps") system("kill -KILL "$1) }'
```

Have fun but use it with caution. I generally don't like system commands in gawk, certainly not the "kill" command.

Comment: Can we do it without system commands.How?

Comment: Here its HP unix and there is no gawk in HP unix

Comment: You'll need system command but I don't like commands like kill in gawk. I think until and unless it is absolutely necessary, execute kill manually.

Comment: replace gawk by awk. It won't create any difference in this case. Command will become `ps| awk '{ if ($4 != "COMMAND" && $4 != "sh" && $4 != "ps") system("kill -KILL "$1) }'`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than parse the output of `ps`, customize it to your liking.

If `ps`'s filtering options are enough to make it show exactly the set of processes you want to kill, then specify `-o pid=` to only show the PID column, with no header line.

```
ps … -o pid=
 1234
56789
```

Since the output contains only digits and whitespace, you can use it directly in a command substitution:

```
kill $(ps … -o pid=)
```

If you need further processing, use `-o` to select the columns and order that you want. See the `ps` manual on your system for the supported column names; [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ps.html) specifies a few. Add a `=` after each column to suppress the header line.

```
kill $(p=$(sh -c 'echo $PPID');
       ps -o pid= -o ppid= -o tty= -o comm= |
       awk -v "tty=${TTY#/dev/}" -v o=$$ -v p=$p '
           $1 != o && $1 != p && $2 != p && $3 == tty && $4 != "sh" {print $1}
       ')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this sort of thing frequently, install proctools.

```
pkill -v -KILL ps
```

kills everything that isn't ps.